# PHP Joomla moving a menu separator from right to left of the menu item

Tags: php, joomla, menu

I'd like to move the menu separator ([look here](http://aurorasvoice.org/images/button.jpg)) currently just after (to the right) of the menu item "Sometitle" to just before (to the left) it, making a separator just after the menu item "Donate" and just before the menu item "Sometitle". Is this accomplishable via the Joomla software,and if so how do I go about doing it, or do I have to accomplish this myself (via JavaScript/CSS). If it's only doable via JavaScript/CSS,any tips would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Just an FYI, the Sometitle element has a CSS ruling of 400px margin-left and float right to give it the right justified outcome.

Comment: Hey guys. You can get a bit more of an idea about the CSS if you go to http://aurorasvoice.org
#horiz-menu and .moomenu  and .topdaddy
are mentioned in template_css.css, menustyle4.css, and style9.css this might help a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is 'Some Title' a specific module or is part of the menu? I would make a second menu module for that item and instead of applying that margin you can put 'float:right' to the module div so you don't waste all that space.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can make a 'dummy' menu item before 'Some Title'. Make it invisible with css so it shows only the separator. That's one option, I should take a look at the actual css code and html layout to give you more ideas. But definitely you can solve this with css.

Comment: I cannot do a dummy menu item because I actually updated the CSS for the Sometitle element to be 400px margin-left from the most previous menu item, giving it the right-justified outcome.

Comment: Is 'Some Title' a specific module or is part of the menu?
I would make a second menu module for that item and instead of applying that margin you can put 'float:right'  to the module div so you don't waste all that space.

Comment: Can you create an answer with this so I can close this question and mark your answer as correct?

Answer (score 0):

Joomla way:

Create another menu for that item (and remove it from the left menu), use the same style for the `<li>` items in both menus (of course, place each `<ul>` according to your design).

CSS way:

Set the 'Sometitle' item like this (replace the **X** for the right item id):

```
.menuClass .itemX {background-position-x:0%;}
```

JS way:

Set the css properties as above.